# Confused by the java sychronized, monitor, wait() and notify()

Tags: java, android, multithreading

If these statements are true:

1. When a thread enter a sychronized region(method or block), it will get the object monitor, then there is no wait() or notify() call in the region, so when exit the region, it lost the monitor.
2. When a thread call wait() in a sychronized region, it will set the status of itself to blocked AND lost the monitor. The thread schedule is triggered, another thread will run.
3. When a thread(call it thread A) call notify() in a sychronized region, JVM will choice a thread(call it thread B) who is waiting the monitor arbitrarily and set its status to Runnable.
4. A thread with a higher priority than the thread currently running enters the Runnable state. The lower priority thread is preempted and the higher priority thread is scheduled to run.

Question:

So in case 3, if the thread B has higher priority, a thread schedule will happen and the thread B will run. Now thread A still has monitor, how can thread B run?

Comment: Thread B has to reacquire the monitor before it can continue, basically...

Comment: That is 4 questions.

Answer (score 1):

**So in case 3, if the thread B has higher priority, a thread schedule will happen and the thread B will run. Now thread A still has monitor, how can thread B run?** - *Wrong*.

Thread-B will not start *executing* once Thread-A calls `notify()`.It still has to get the lock on the Object currently being held by thread-A. Once thread-A *exits* the synchronized block or calls `wait()`, thread-B can get the lock on the Object (once Thread-A exits the synchronized block or calls `wait()`, it releases the lock). Once thread-B has the lock on that object, it starts executing.

Even if Thread-B has higher priority than thread-A, it has to wait until it gets the lock.